# typoscript menu foundation containing page contents

Tags: menu, zurb-foundation, typoscript

I am looking to develop a menu with 3 levels dropdown menu with foundation 5.5.0 ! A menu containing the contents of a page. I can see the title, but the content does not change when I change page or tab (links are : | ---1--- |... and Title 11, Title 12, Title 13 ... and link 1 to link 8 or more). It initialises to the content of the activated page via the link of the menu. For each title I want to display the content of the page in question. I want the page not to be displayed elsewhere than in the menu.

```
[ --- 1 --- (*)][--- 2 --- ][--- 3 --- ]
| Title 11      | Title 12      | Title 13      |
| Content 11    | Content 12    | Content 13    |      
|               |               |               |
| link 1        | link 4        | link 6        |
| link 2        | link 5        | link 7        |               
| link 3        |               | link 8        |
```

(*) actived.

Menu containing page contents :
I can display 'Content 11' but it appears everywhere in all the other 'Content' (Content 11 = Content 12 = Content 13). And not the corresponding content of the title. When I click on another link it is this one that takes the place of the other and that is displayed everywhere in the 'Content x'.

The menu itself works.

```
    lib.menuprincipal = COA
lib.menuprincipal {
    wrap (
      <div data-magellan-expedition="fixed" class="large-12 column" data-magellan>
        <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
      |
        </nav>
      </div>
    )

    # NavBar Header
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        data = leveltitle:0
        typolink {
            parameter.data = parameters : allParams
            ATagParams = class="TestAddParamClass"
            title.data = leveltitle:0
          #forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
        }

        wrap (
            <ul class="title-area">
              <li class="name">
                 <div class="show-for-small left">
                    <div id="poslogomin1" class="right">
                       <h2>Titre site/h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">|</li>
            </ul>
        )
    }

    # menu
    20 = HMENU
    20 {
        #entryLevel = 0
        wrap (
               <section class="top-bar-section">
                    <ul class="left">                            
                        |      
                    </ul>
               </section>
        )

        # Premier niveau
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
          entryLevel = 0
          #wrap = |  
          expAll = 1   
          maxItems = 5             

          NO = 1
          NO {       
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            stdWrap.cObject = COA
            stdWrap.cObject{

                10 = TEXT
                10.typolink.no_cache = 1
                10.typolink.ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                10.typolink.parameter.field = uid

                10.cObject = COA
                10.cObject{                               
                        10 = TEXT
                        10.wrap = <div class="tile tile|">
                        10.field = layout

                        20 = TEXT
                        20.wrap = <div class="title"><h2 style='color:darkblue'>|</h2></div>
                        20.field = title

                        30 = TEXT                 
                        30.wrap = <div class = "subtitle"><h2 style='color:darkred'>|</h2></div>
                        30.field = subtitle      

                        40 = CONTENT        
                        40.wrap = <div class = "subtitle"><div>|</div></div>                                                              
                        40 {
                          table = tt_content
                            select {
                              where= colPos=0
                              uidInList.field = this
                            }
                        }
                        40.field < styles.content.get

                        50 = TEXT
                        50.value = </div>
               }          
            }      
          }          

          NO.wrapItemAndSub =  <li class="has-dropdown">|</li>

          ACT = 1
          ACT.wrapItemAndSub =  <li class="has-dropdown">|</li>

          IFSUB = 1
          IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub =  <li class="has-dropdown">|</li>         
        }//1

        # Deuxième niveau
        2 < .1      
        2 = TMENU
        2 {  
          #entryLevel = 0
          maxItems = 5
            wrap (
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li>
                     <div class="row mynav" id="nav-2">
                       |
                     </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            )
            expAll = 1

            NO = 1 

            NO.wrapItemAndSub =  <div class="large-3 medium-6 column">|</div>   
            NO.stdWrap.wrap = <h2 style='color:darkgreen'>|</h2>

          ACT < .NO
          CUR < .NO
          IFSUB < .NO
          ACTIFSUB < .NO        
        }//2

        # Troisième niveau
        3 = TMENU
        3 {    
          #entryLevel = 0
          maxItems = 5

          wrap = <p>|</p>
        }//3               
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in typoscript, can you help me? Thank you !
Best regards.

Comment: 1. Which TYPO3 version do you use? 2. Do you use css_styled_content or fluid_styles_content?

Comment: Typo3 8.7.4 and fluid_styles_content.

Comment: At point lib.menuprincipal.20.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject.10.cObject.44 you first declare your content object and than assign styles.content.get.
1. This is not necceassary because the default TS of styles.content.get is:
styles.content.get = CONTENT
styles.content.get {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        orderBy = sorting
        where = {#colPos}=0
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Hello i have make that at 40 point and add :

```
40 = CONTENT
40 {
   table = tt_content  
       select {
         orderBy = sorting
         pidInList.field = uid                              
         where = {#colPos}=0 and deleted = 0 and hidden = 0  
       }
   renderObj = COA
   renderObj {
     10 = TEXT
     10.stdWrap.field = header

     10.stdWrap.wrap = <div class = "subtitle"><div>|</div></div>

     20 = TEXT
     20.stdWrap.field = bodytext

     20.stdWrap.wrap = <p>|</p>
  }
}
```

Now this is correct.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

At point lib.menuprincipal.20.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject.10.cObject.44 you first declare your content object and than assign styles.content.get to the field.

1. This is not necceassary because the default TS of styles.content.get is:

   ```
   styles.content.get = CONTENT  
   styles.content.get {  
       table = tt_content  
       select {
           orderBy = sorting
           where = {#colPos}=0
       }
   }
   ```
2. See the new colPos definition in the where clause. I think this could be a problem.
3. You need

   ```
       40.renderObj = TEXT
       40.renderObj.field = yourfield
   ```

   See [TYPO3 Dokumentation Section CONTENT](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8-dev/ContentObjects/Content/#) for more info.